# Postfix: whitelist host for specific sender

Tags: postfix

I have configured postfix like this to prevent spam (I am mydomain.com):

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions         =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_client_access
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_helo_access
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
...
```

Because of that, I have the following logs:

```
Jul 30 00:04:14 stormrage postfix/smtpd[28116]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from srv-exchange.anett.fr[80.118.5.170]: 450 4.7.1 <emailsecurity.domain.com>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<sender@domain.com> to=<my@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<emailsecurity.domain.com>
```

This example log is a legitimate email, so I whitelist in check_helo_access like this:

```
/etc/postfix/check_helo_access:
emailsecurity.domain.com OK
...
```

It works, but I think the whitelisting may be strengthen.
I can whitelist by host or by sender, but not both.

How can I whitelist an email based on specific sender/domain-sender when sent though specific host ?

Comment: I agree but I'm not sure this is doable. However, using your configuration plus some regular antispam should lead to pretty good results.

Comment: Yes and furthurmore this part of the conf is useless against spam received from hacked/fake account (from gmail or microsoft live), but this is for personal and small business use, so I can accept to manually fix false positive (for now).

Comment: I don't understand your sentence: 'It works, but I think the whitelisting may be strengthen.' What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can whitelist by host or by sender, but not both.

actually you could. All you need is to use [smtpd_restriction_classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = sender_white_list
sender_white_list = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_client_access, reject

smtpd_helo_restrictions =
  check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_helo_access
  permit_mynetworks
  permit_sasl_authenticated

/etc/postfix/check_helo_access
emailsecurity.domain.com sender_white_list

/etc/postfix/check_client_access
80.118.5.170 OK
```

Comment: smtpd_restriction_classes is not practical however.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I know, there is no other way to get such behavior in the postfix. If you need more flexible rules you could try to write you own policy service as described at http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html